# Overlay multiple stat_function calls in ggplot2

Tags: r, function, overlay, plot, ggplot2

I have two data frames `raw` and `coef`:

- one containing raw data
- the other containing modelling coefficients that I have derived from the raw data.

The first data frame `raw` contains :

- `Time` (0 to 900 seconds)
- `OD` for many Variants and four runs.

The second data frame `coef` contains :

- one row per Variant/run combination, with the individual coefficients (`M`, `D.1` and `t0.1`) in that row.

I have plotted the raw data split per Variant and colored by `runID`, without a problem. But, now I want to overlay the model curves according to the `runID`.

Since the modelling coefficients are in a different data frames, with different dimensions, I can't just `cbind` them. `stat_function` won't work for me. I can get only one curve showing at a time.

I have tried with a `for loop`, adding a `stat_function` layer each time:

```
p <- ggplot(temp, aes(Time, OD)) + geom_point(aes(colour = runID), size = 2) #works fine!
calc <- function(x){temp.n$M[ID] * (1 - exp(temp.n$D.1[ID] * temp.n$t0.1[ID] - x)))}
for(ID in 1:length(unique(temp.n$runID))) {
  p <- p + stat_function(fun = calc)
}
print(p)
```

At the end, all `p` returns is the plot of the raw data, and the final curve from the looping bit. `p` seems to revert to its original state every time I try to add a new `stat_function` layer.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Perhaps the easiest fix would be to merge the data.frames. Is that feasible?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? The problem is your use of variable scoping.

Answer (score 4):

Following on the solution [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376967/using-stat-function-and-facet-wrap-together-in-ggplot2-in-r), you might have to imitate the effect of `stat_function` yourself. Since you do not give a reproducible example, I created a simple one that hopefully mimics your problem:

```
library(ggplot2)
reg.fun <- function(x, par1, par2){exp(-x*par1) + par2} #functional form
reg <- data.frame(g=factor(1:3), par1=(1:3)/10, par2=1:3)  #parameters for 3 groups

#generate data from reg.fun
dd <- expand.grid(x=0:9, g=reg$g)         #set x values, and 3 groups from reg
dd <- merge(dd, reg)                      #"import" parameters
dd$mn <- with(dd, reg.fun(x, par1, par2)) #value of function for given x's
dd$y <- rnorm(30, mean=dd$mn, sd=0.5)     #add variability
dd <- subset(dd, select=c(g,x,y))         #remove auxiliary variables 

#similarly to above generate values for the function on a fine grid of x values
pred.dd <- expand.grid(x=seq(0,9, length=101), g=levels(dd$g))
pred.dd <- merge(pred.dd, reg)
pred.dd$y <- with(pred.dd, reg.fun(x, par1, par2))

#draw the plot
p <- qplot(x,y, colour=g, data=dd)  #scatterplot of data
p + geom_line(data=pred.dd)         #add the curves of the functions
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with you. In a very non-elegant solution, the only solution I found was to hack the stat functions together something like this:

```
p <- ggplot(temp, aes(Time, OD)) + geom_point(aes(colour = runID), size = 2) #works fine!

calc <- function(x){temp.n$M[ID] * (1 - exp(temp.n$D.1[ID] * temp.n$t0.1[ID] - x)))}
    p <- p +
      stat_function(fun = function(x){temp.n$M[1] * (1 - exp(temp.n$D.1[1] * temp.n$t0.1[1] - x)))) + 
      stat_function(fun = function(x){temp.n$M[2] * (1 - exp(temp.n$D.1[2] * temp.n$t0.1[2] - x)))) +
      stat_function(fun = function(x){temp.n$M[3] * (1 - exp(temp.n$D.1[3] * temp.n$t0.1[3] - x)))) +
      # etc
```

Which is fine if you only have a few lines to add, but not if you have many.