# How to add gaussian curve to histogram created with qplot?

Tags: r, histogram, ggplot2

I have question probably similar to [Fitting a density curve to a histogram in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497539/fitting-a-density-curve-to-a-histogram-in-r). Using qplot I have created 7 histograms with this command:

```
 (qplot(V1, data=data, binwidth=10, facets=V2~.)
```

For each slice, I would like to add a fitting gaussian curve. When I try to use `lines()` method, I get error:

```
Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : 
plot.new has not been called yet
```

What is the command to do it correctly?

Comment: You can't mix base graphics functions (`lines()` etc) with grid graphics as used by the **gpplot2** and **lattice** packages.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried `stat_function`?

```
+ stat_function(fun = dnorm)
```

You'll probably want to plot the histograms using `aes(y = ..density..)` in order to plot the density values rather than the counts.

A lot of useful information can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376967/using-stat-function-and-facet-wrap-together-in-ggplot2-in-r) question, including some advice on plotting different normal curves on different facets.

Here are some examples:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = c(rnorm(100),rnorm(100,2,0.5)), 
                  a = rep(letters[1:2],each = 100))
```

Overlay a single normal density on each facet:

```
ggplot(data = dat,aes(x = x)) + 
  facet_wrap(~a) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..)) + 
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, colour = "red")
```

[image]

From the question I linked to, create a separate data frame with the different normal curves:

```
grid <- with(dat, seq(min(x), max(x), length = 100))
normaldens <- ddply(dat, "a", function(df) {
  data.frame( 
    predicted = grid,
    density = dnorm(grid, mean(df$x), sd(df$x))
  )
})
```

And plot them separately using `geom_line`:

```
ggplot(data = dat,aes(x = x)) + 
    facet_wrap(~a) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..)) + 
    geom_line(data = normaldens, aes(x = predicted, y = density), colour = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: i am very beginner in R, just have it for few days. I will take a look at it, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 5):

`ggplot2` uses a different graphics paradigm than base graphics.  (Although you can use `grid` graphics with it, the best way is to add a new `stat_function` layer to the plot.  The `ggplot2` code is the following.

Note that I couldn't get this to work using `qplot`, but the transition to `ggplot` is reasonably straighforward, the most important difference is that your data *must* be in data.frame format.

Also note the explicit mapping of the y aesthetic `aes=aes(y=..density..))` - this is slighly unusual but takes the `stat_function` results and maps it to the data:

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(V1 <- rnorm(700), V2=sample(LETTERS[1:7], 700, replace=TRUE))
ggplot(data, aes(x=V1)) + 
  stat_bin(aes(y=..density..)) + 
  stat_function(fun=dnorm) + 
  facet_grid(V2~.)
```

[image]