# Assign Weibull densities within groups of dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, probability-density, weibull

I am trying to create a new column on my data.frame (`df`) with values of Weibull densities.

I need to assign densities for vector of quantiles (w) taking into account groups in this df.
The subsets are delimited by the variable "plot".

Each plot has specific Weibull parameters in which the densities should be originated from.
The parameters are stored in `df_2`.

Reproducible example:

```
set.seed(25)

w = rweibull(1200,10,28)
plot = data.frame(c(rep.int(1,300),rep.int(2,300),rep.int(3,300),rep.int(4,300)))
   names(plot)[1] = c("plot")

df = cbind(plot,w)

df_2=data.frame(cbind(c(1,2,3,4),c(28,27,26,25),c(9,9.5,8,7)))
   names(df_2)[1:3] = c("plot","scale","shape")
```

I tried to adapt a code from hadley's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376967/using-stat-function-and-facet-wrap-together-in-ggplot2-in-r), but did not succeed.

```
library(plyr)
weibull_density <- ddply(df, "plot", function(x) {
  data.frame(
    density = dweibull(df$w, scale=df_2$scale, shape=df_2$shape)
  )
})

nrow(weibull_density)
[1] 4800
```

It returns a data.frame with 4800 rows (I was expecting 1200).

I also took a look in examples provided in `?ddply` help page, but could not figure out how to adapt it to this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obtain 4 values because `df_2` has 4 rows. You need to tell `R` to use, e.g., the first row of `df_2` for the `w` values for `plot == 1`.

The following code produces the expected output:

```
weibull_density <- transform(df, 
  density = as.vector(sapply(unique(plot), function(x) 
    dweibull(w[plot %in% x], scale = df_2$scale[x], shape = df_2$shape[x]))))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this maybe the simplest??

```
> df3=merge(df, df_2)
> res=mapply(dweibull, x=df3$w, shape=df3$shape, scale=df3$scale)

> head(res)
[1] 0.11900795 0.09575625 0.09021534 0.04742028 0.08339647 0.01091331

> length(res)
[1] 1200
```

maybe???

Comment: of course there is more overhead.. but for this example it's conceptually clear...hmmm...