# Plot multiple normal curves in same plot

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

I'm interested in creating an example plot (ideally using ggplot) that will display two normal curves with different means and different standard deviations.  I've discovered ggplot's stat_function() argument but am not sure how to get a second curve on the same plot.

This code produces one curve:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-4, 4)), aes(x)) + stat_function(fun = dnorm)
```

Any advice on ways to get a second curve?  Or maybe simpler to do in base package plotting?

Comment: Perhaps this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376967/using-stat-function-and-facet-wrap-together-in-ggplot2-in-r

Comment: It's 3 lines in base R plotting. I think this is an instance where it's just easier: `plot(NA,xlim=c(-4,4),ylim=c(0,1));curve(dnorm(x,mean=1,sd=0.5), col="blue", add=TRUE);curve(dnorm(x,mean=0,sd=1), col="red", add=TRUE)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just in case you also want to do it in `ggplot` (it's also 3 lines...).

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-4, 4)), aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 0, sd = 1), col='red') +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 1, sd = .5), col='blue')
```

In case you have more than two curves, it may be better to use `mapply` for this. That makes it slightly more difficult. But for many functions it is probably worth it.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-4, 4)), aes(x)) + 
  mapply(function(mean, sd, col) {
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean, sd = sd), col = col)
  }, 
  # enter means, standard deviations and colors here
  mean = c(0, 1, .5), 
  sd = c(1, .5, 2), 
  col = c('red', 'blue', 'green')
)
```

Comment: This is great! How do I add a legend for the lines?

Comment: it seems you don't using + while have the same effect.