# Plotting multiple normal curves with ggplot2 without hardcoding means and standard deviations

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, normal-distribution, mapply

I have a vector of means and standard deviations, and I would like to plot the densities corresponding to these means and standard deviations in the same plot using `ggplot2`. I used `mapply` and `gather` to solve this problem, but it's quite a lot of lines of code for something which I think should be trivial:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# generate data
my_data <- data.frame(mean =  c(0.032, 0.04, 0.038, 0.113, 0.105, 0.111),
                      stdev = c(0.009, 0.01, 0.01, 0.005, 0.014, 0.006), 
                      test = factor(c("Case_01", "Case_02", "Case_03", "Case_04",
                                      "Case_05", "Case_06")))

# points at which to evaluate the Gaussian densities
x <- seq(-0.05, 0.2, by = 0.001)

# build list of Gaussian density vectors based on means and standard deviations
pdfs <- mapply(dnorm, mean = my_data$mean, sd = my_data$stdev, MoreArgs = list(x = x),
               SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

# add group names
names(pdfs) <- my_data$test

# convert list to dataframe
pdfs <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, pdfs)
pdfs$x <- x

# convert dataframe to tall format
tall_df <- gather(pdfs, test, density, -x)

# build plot
p <- ggplot(tall_df, aes(color = test, x = x, y = density)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_segment(data = my_data, aes(color = test, x = mean, y = 0, 
                                   xend = mean, yend = 100), linetype = "dashed") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-1, 100))
print(p)
```

[image]This is very similar to:

[Plot multiple normal curves in same plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27009641/plot-multiple-normal-curves-in-same-plot)

and as a matter of fact, [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27012775/1711271) uses `mapply`, so that confirms me that I'm on the right track. However, what I don't like of that answer is that it hard-codes means and standard deviations in the `mapply` call. This won't work in my use case, because I read the real data from disk (of course, in the MRE I skipped the data reading part for simplicity). Is it possible to simplify my code, without sacrificing readability, and without hard-coding the mean and standard deviation vectors in the `mapply` call?

**EDIT** maybe the call to `mapply` may be avoided by using the package `mvtnorm`, but I don't think that affords any real simplification here. Most of my code comes after the call to `mapply`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save some coding using `purrr::pmap_df`, which does the row binding automatically after constructing a data frame for each `mean-stdev` pair:

<sub>Assume `my_data` has the input columns in the order or `mean, stdev, test` and `test` is of character class.</sub>

```
library(purrr)
tall_df2 <- pmap_df(my_data, ~ data_frame(x = x, test = ..3, density = dnorm(x, ..1, ..2)))
```

---

With data:

```
my_data <- data.frame(mean =  c(0.032, 0.04, 0.038, 0.113, 0.105, 0.111),
                      stdev = c(0.009, 0.01, 0.01, 0.005, 0.014, 0.006), 
                      test = c("Case_01", "Case_02", "Case_03", "Case_04", "Case_05", "Case_06"), 
                      stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Plot:

```
p <- ggplot(tall_df2, aes(color = factor(test), x = x, y = density)) + 
      geom_line() +
      geom_segment(data = my_data, aes(color = test, x = mean, y = 0, 
                                       xend = mean, yend = 100), linetype = "dashed") +
      coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-1, 100))

print(p)
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: cool! Could you explain what's the goal of `pmap_df`? I'm not familiar with `purrr`

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you had to use the `..i` sintax. For sure, `tall_df2 <- pmap_df(my_data, ~ data_frame(x = x, test = test, density = dnorm(x, mean, stdev)))` doesn't work, thus your syntax is the right one. But I don't understand why

Comment: `pmap_df` is sort of a combination of `pmap` + `bind_rows`, and `pmap` does similar things to `mapply` but with different syntax. So instead of doing `mapply(f, a, b, c)` you do `pmap(list(a, b, c),f)`, this is convenient if you already have the data together, in your case a data frame. And finally it calls `bind_rows` for you to save you the `do.call(..., rbind)`. For more about syntax, see `?pmap`. If you want to match arguments by name, you need to construct a function explicitly `pmap_df(my_data, function(mean, stdev, test) data_frame(x = x, test = test, density = dnorm(x, mean, stdev)))`

Comment: amazing! I will use the match by name approach - more readable, IMO, and also doesn't make assumptions about the order of columns. Since in the real use case I read data from disk, I cannot be sure about the column order - but I know the column names.

Comment: The `x` argument should probably be replaced by the sequence in the question (`seq(-0.05, 0.2, by = 0.001)`) for clarity.