# How to plot the missing normal distribution when doing logistic regression?

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic-regression

I am working on a paper demonstrating the use of logistic regression. I am trying to demonstrate that a regular linear probability model is insufficient when the dependent variable is dichotomous as the error terms doesn't represent a normal distribution.

I got two variables in my dataset:

- gender: Male, Female
- height: A continuous variable containing the height of every observation.

My logistic model is trying to predict whether the observation is male or female based on their height.

I guess the distribution would be some kind of double gaussian distribution but how do I plot this visually?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Perhaps this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27009641/plot-multiple-normal-curves-in-same-plot

Comment: Complicating further, males and females are inherently differently distributed as to height as well as other relative bodily dimensions as demonstrated in geometric morphometric studies, see especially [Julien Claude](https://www.academia.edu/23070501/Height_and_body_mass_influence_on_human_body_outlines_A_quantitative_approach_using_an_elliptic_Fourier_analysis) perhaps for a cite.