# Apply MASS::fitdistr to multiple data by a factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, apply, beta-distribution

My question is at the end in **bold.**

I know how to fit the beta distribution to some data. For instance:

```
library(Lahman)
library(dplyr)

# clean up the data and calculate batting averages by playerID
batting_by_decade <- Batting %>%
  filter(AB > 0) %>%
  group_by(playerID, Decade = round(yearID - 5, -1)) %>%
  summarize(H = sum(H), AB = sum(AB)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(AB > 500) %>%
  mutate(average = H / AB)

# fit the beta distribution
library(MASS)
m <- MASS::fitdistr(batting_by_decade$average, dbeta,
                    start = list(shape1 = 1, shape2 = 10))

alpha0 <- m$estimate[1]
beta0 <- m$estimate[2]

# plot the histogram of data and the beta distribution
ggplot(career_filtered) +
  geom_histogram(aes(average, y = ..density..), binwidth = .005) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) dbeta(x, alpha0, beta0), color = "red",
                size = 1) +
  xlab("Batting average")
```

Which yields:

[image]

Now I want to calculate different beta parameters `alpha0` and `beta0` for each `batting_by_decade$Decade` column of the data so I end up with 15 parameter sets, and 15 beta distributions that I can fit to this ggplot of batting averages faceted by Decade:

```
batting_by_decade %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=average)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Decade)
```

[image]

I can hard code this by filtering for each decade, and passing that decade's worth of data into the `fidistr` function, repeating this for all decades, but **is there a way of calculating all beta parameters per decade quickly and reproducibly, perhaps with one of the apply functions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage `summarise` together with two custom functions for this:

```
getAlphaEstimate = function(x) {MASS::fitdistr(x, dbeta,start = list(shape1 = 1, shape2 = 10))$estimate[1]}

getBetaEstimate = function(x) {MASS::fitdistr(x, dbeta,start = list(shape1 = 1, shape2 = 10))$estimate[2]}

batting_by_decade %>%
  group_by(Decade) %>%
  summarise(alpha = getAlphaEstimate(average),
         beta = getBetaEstimate(average)) -> decadeParameters
```

However, you will not be able to plot it with `stat_summary` according to Hadley's post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1379074/3124909

Comment: I like this answer a lot. It's much more elegant that what I made, see below. Thank you CMichael! I also didn't know you could end a pipe with an assignment. Very cool.

Comment: Thank you - I remember when one of my students first used the assignment at the end of the pipe and I was dumbfolded that you can do that. I think it is really elegant. Also, I feel there should be a way of avoiding the duplicated `fitdistr` call in my code which may be costly in large data scenarios but I just did not come up with it ;)

Comment: Although discontinued the stackoverflow documentation on pipes had a nice section on pipe variants: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/652/pipe-operators-and-others/13622/assignment-with

Comment: I got an idea re:avoiding the duplicated ```fitdistr```, which I just put in my post. The only thing it's missing is unlisting the second column of the data.frame.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how you'd go from generating dummy data all the way through to plotting.

```
temp.df <- data_frame(yr = 10*187:190,
                      al = rnorm(length(yr), mean = 4, sd = 2),
                      be = rnorm(length(yr), mean = 10, sd = 2)) %>% 
  group_by(yr, al, be) %>% 
  do(data_frame(dats = rbeta(100, .$al, .$be)))
```

First I made up some scale parameters for four years, grouped by each combination, and then used `do` to create a dataframe with 100 samples from each distribution. Aside from knowing the "true" parameters, this dataframe should look a lot like your original data: a vector of samples with an associated year.

---

```
temp.ests <- temp.df %>% 
  group_by(yr, al, be) %>% 
  summarise(ests = list(MASS::fitdistr(dats, dbeta, start = list(shape1 = 1, shape2 = 1))$estimate)) %>% 
  unnest %>% 
  mutate(param = rep(letters[1:2], length(ests)/2)) %>% 
  spread(key = param, value = ests)
```

This is the bulk of your question here, very much solved the way you solved it. If you step through this snippet line by line, you'll see you have a dataframe with a column of type `list`, containing `<dbl [2]>` in each row. When you `unnest()` it splits those two numbers into separate rows, so then we identify them by adding a column that goes "a, b, a, b, ..." and `spread` them back apart to get two columns with one row for each year. Here you can also see how closely `fitdistr` matched the true population we sampled from, looking at `a` vs `al` and `b` vs `be`.

---

```
temp.curves <- temp.ests %>% 
  group_by(yr, al, be, a, b) %>% 
  do(data_frame(prop = 1:99/100,
                trueden = dbeta(prop, .$al, .$be),
                estden = dbeta(prop, .$a, .$b)))
```

Now we turn that process inside out to generate the data to plot the curves. For each row, we use `do` to make a dataframe with a sequence of values `prop`, and calculate the beta density at each value for both the true population parameters and our estimated sample parameters.

---

```
ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(data = temp.df, aes(dats, y = ..density..), colour = "black", fill = "white") +
  geom_line(data = temp.curves, aes(prop, trueden, color = "population"), size = 1) +
  geom_line(data = temp.curves, aes(prop, estden, color = "sample"), size = 1) +
  geom_text(data = temp.ests, 
            aes(1, 2, label = paste("hat(alpha)==", round(a, 2))), 
            parse = T, hjust = 1) +
  geom_text(data = temp.ests, 
            aes(1, 1, label = paste("hat(beta)==", round(b, 2))), 
            parse = T, hjust = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~yr)
```

Finally we put it together, plotting a histogram of our sample data. Then a line from our curve data for the true density. Then a line from our curve data for our estimated density. Then some labels from our parameter estimate data to show the sample parameters, and facets by year.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an apply solution, but I prefer @CMichael's dplyr solution.

```
calc_beta <- function(decade){
  dummy <- batting_by_decade %>% 
    dplyr::filter(Decade == decade) %>% 
    dplyr::select(average)

  m <- fitdistr(dummy$average, dbeta, start = list(shape1 = 1, shape2 = 10))

  alpha0 <- m$estimate[1]
  beta0 <- m$estimate[2]

  return(c(alpha0,beta0))
}

decade <- seq(1870, 2010, by =10)
params <- sapply(decade, calc_beta)
colnames(params) <- decade
```

Re: @CMichael's comment about avoiding a double `fitdistr`, we could rewrite the function to `getAlphaBeta`.

```
getAlphaBeta = function(x) {MASS::fitdistr(x, dbeta,start = list(shape1 = 1, shape2 = 10))$estimate}

batting_by_decade %>%
  group_by(Decade) %>%
  summarise(params = list(getAlphaBeta(average))) -> decadeParameters

decadeParameters$params[1] # it works!
```

Now we just need to unlist the second column in a nice way....

Comment: Of course list return value - after that you can look into the `broom` package for handling many models. Hadley's R4DS has a very good chapter on it: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html Essentially you manage list colums all the way.

Comment: Excellent. I'm on chapter 5 right now, but when I get to chapter 25, I'll come back to this post.

Comment: For unlisting, you use `tidyr::unnest()`.