# ggplot2: Releveling factors for sequentially added layers

Tags: r, ggplot2, levels

I am writing a plotting method for class `"foo"`. I would like this plot function to take multiple `foo` objects and plot them on the same graph.

## The Code

```
#parabola function
parabolas <- function(x, parm) {
  y <- parm[1]*(x^2)+parm[2]*x+parm[3]
  return(y)
}
#make foo object
make_foo <- function(a, b, c) {
   x <- runif(100, 0 , 20)
   y <- parabolas(x = x, parm = c(a,b,c)) + rnorm(100, mean = 100 ,sd = 100)
   foo <- list(data = data.frame(x = x, y = y), parameters = c(a,b,c))
   class(foo) <- "foo"
   return(foo)
}


#plot function
plot.foo <- function(x, 
                 ...,
                 labels) {

 a <- ggplot(NULL, aes(x = x, y = y))

 foo.list <- list(x, ...)
 #browser()
 #build plot
 for(i in 1:length(foo.list)){
   foo.obj <- foo.list[[i]]
   foo.obj$data$lab <- factor(rep(labels[i], nrow(foo.obj$data)), levels = labels)
a <- a + geom_point(data = foo.obj$data, size = 5, alpha = .7, aes(color = lab))
a <- a + stat_function(data = foo.obj$data,
                       fun = parabolas, 
                       args = list(parm = foo.obj$parameters), size = 1.2)
 }
 return(a)
}
```

## The Problem

ggplot will relevel the factor levels of `lab` according to the alphabetical order of the factor labels. I do not know how to choose the factor level order for `lab` when adding these layers sequentially. I would like for the first element of `labels` to correspond to the first foo object plotted, and the second element to correspond to the second foo object, and so forth and so forth.

```
foo1 <- make_foo(2, 10, 3)
foo2 <- make_foo(-6, -3, 2000)
plot(foo1, foo2, labels = c("obj1","obj2"))
#label for foo1 is "obj1" and label for foo2 is "obj2"
plot(foo1, foo2, labels = c("obj3","obj2"))
#label for foo1 should be "obj3" and label for foo2 should be "obj2"
```

## The motivation

The reason I structure the plot function like this as opposed to binding the data frames together and assigning the correct factor levels to `lab` is because in that particular case, `facet_wrap` and `stat_function` do not work well together. After applying multiple `stat_function` and using `facet_wrap` together, all curves will appear in each panel. This thread illustrates a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376967/using-stat-function-and-facet-wrap-together-in-ggplot2-in-r).
Because I have these different layers limited to different data sets, `facet_wrap` will correctly facet each `stat_function` plot according to the data/parameters used to draw it.

```
plot(foo1, foo2, labels = c("z","a")) + facet_wrap(~lab, scales = "free")
#Shows facet_wrap works as intended but the labels for foo1 and foo2 are
#still not in the intended order
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually override the order of the color scale by setting the `limits`. Here is how:

```
plot.foo <- function(x, 
                     ...,
                     labels) {

  a <- ggplot(NULL, aes(x = x, y = y))

  foo.list <- list(x, ...)
  #browser()
  #build plot
  for(i in 1:length(foo.list)){
    foo.obj <- foo.list[[i]]
    foo.obj$data$lab <- factor(rep(labels[i], nrow(foo.obj$data)), levels = labels)
    a <- a + geom_point(data = foo.obj$data, size = 5, alpha = .7, aes(color = lab))
    a <- a + stat_function(data = foo.obj$data,
                           fun = parabolas, 
                           args = list(parm = foo.obj$parameters), size = 1.2)
  }

  ### added line:
  a <- a + scale_color_discrete(limits = labels)
  ###

  return(a)
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it better to use `limits` or `breaks` in this situation?

Comment: You could use either. Not sure if there is any reason to have preference either way.

Comment: I was thinking `breaks` because OP did not intend to exclude any levels. But both give the same result in this situation.

Comment: That's true, if you only provide one label only that one will be shown (the other will just be grey). You could potentially use this if you want to highlight one curve out of several. Limits also allow you to add extra levels to the scale that are not in your data, e.g. `plot(foo1, foo2, labels = c("obj3","obj2",'this is another level))`. I guess that could be useful in some cases.